# Angular2 : two way binding inside parent/child component

Tags: angular

Version: "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.6"

I would like to implement a two way binding inside a parent/child component case.

On my child component, I'm using two-way binding to display text while editing.

Child component (`InputTestComponent [selector:'input-test']`):

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #testform="ngForm">
    {{name}}
    <textarea #textarea [(ngModel)]="name" ngControl="name" name="name"></textarea>
    <button type="submit">Go</button>
</form>
```

Then, I would like to propagate this change to his parent component.
I tried with `[(name)]="name"` with no success.

Parent component:

```
<div>
  {{name}}
  <input-test [(name)]="name"></input-test>
</div>
```

[Code sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/GO8BCcJleyNRURB29OOC)

What the easiest way to do it (less verbose) ?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

For 2-way binding use `@Input()` and `@Output()`. The names should be `propName` and `propNameChange` to allow the shorthand binding syntax `[(propName)]="someModel"` otherwise you'd need the longer version `[propName]="someModel" (propNameOtherOutputName)="propName=$event;propNameOtherOutputName.emit($event)"`

```
@Component{
  ...
  template: `
<textarea #textarea [(ngModel)]="name" (ngModelChange)="nameChange.emit($event)" ngControl="name" name="name"></textarea>

`})
export class InputTestComponent {
  @Output() nameChange:EventEmitter<String> = new EventEmitter<String>();
  @Input() name:string;
}
```

Comment: Works... you forgot to mention the need to do banana binding on the parent child property

Comment: This is not example of parent-child banana in a box.

Comment: Of course it is - `<textarea>` is the child and can be a custom component.

Comment: for me (with angular 6) this worked only after I specified the name of the name of the 2-way-binded prop: in component.ts: `@Input('selected') selected; @Output('selectedChange') selectedChange:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();`, in component.html: `<ng-select ... [(ngModel)]="selected" (ngModelChange)="selectedChange.emit($event)"></ng-select>`, in template that uses the component: `<component ... [(selected)]="formFields.okpdCode"></component>`

Answer (score 11):

You can setup two-way data binding between parent and child component in the following ways:

```
<app-child [(counter)]="counter"></app-child>
<app-child [counter]="counter" (counterChange)="counter=$event"></app-child>
<app-child [counter]="counter" (counterChange)="onCounterChange($event)"></app-child>
```

According to [Angular - Template Syntax - Two-way binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#two-way-binding---):

> Angular offers a special two-way data binding syntax for this purpose,
>   [(x)]. The [(x)] syntax combines the brackets of property binding,
>   [x], with the parentheses of event binding, (x).

```
<app-child [(counter)]="counter"></app-child>
```

> The [(x)] syntax is easy to demonstrate when the element has a
>   settable property called x and a corresponding event named xChange.

```
@Input() counter: number;
@Output() counterChange = new EventEmitter<number>();
```

> The two-way binding syntax is really just syntactic sugar for a
>   property binding and an event binding. Angular desugars the
>   ChildComponent binding into this:

```
<app-child [counter]="counter" (counterChange)="counter=$event"></app-child>
```

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-two-way-data-binding-between-parent-and-child-component?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
  <div style="background-color: red; padding: 10px;">
    <div>{{counter}}</div>
    <button (click)="increment()">increment from parent</button>
    <app-child [(counter)]="counter"></app-child>
    <app-child [counter]="counter" (counterChange)="counter=$event"></app-child>
    <app-child [counter]="counter" (counterChange)="onCounterChange($event)"></app-child>
  </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {

  counter = 0;

  increment() {
    this.counter++;
  }

  onCounterChange(counter: number) {
    this.counter = counter;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template: `
  <div style="background-color: green; padding: 10px; margin: 10px;">
    <div>{{counter}}</div>
    <button (click)="increment()">increment from child</button>
  </div>
  `,
})
export class ChildComponent {

  @Input() counter: number;
  @Output() counterChange = new EventEmitter<number>();

  constructor() { }

  increment() {
    this.counterChange.emit(++this.counter);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use input / output elements in the child component, as described below:

```
@Component({
  selector:'input-test'
  template: `
    <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #testform="ngForm">
    {{name}}
      <textarea #textarea [(ngModel)]="name" ngControl="name" name="name"></textarea>
      <button type="submit">Go</button>
    </form>
  `
})
export class InputTestComponent {
  @Input()
  name:string;

  @Output()
  nameChange:EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();
}
```

When a change is detected, you need to fire an event using the  `EventEmitter`:

```
onSubmit() {
  this.nameChange.emit(this.name);
}
```

This way the bound element of the parent component will be automatically updated when using the following syntax:

```
<input-test [(name)]="name"></input-test>
```

You can notice that you can leverage, the `ngModelChange` event if you want to detect input change instead of using form submission:

```
@Component({
  selector:'input-test'
  template: `
    <form #testform="ngForm">
    {{name}}
      <textarea #textarea [ngModel]="name" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" ngControl="name" name="name"></textarea>
    </form>
  `
})
export class InputTestComponent {
  @Input()
  name:string;

  @Output()
  nameChange:EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();

  onChange(newName) {
    this.name = newName;
    this.nameChange.emit(this.name);
  }
}
```

Comment: In your last code snippet, since you use `[ngModel]` instead of `[(ngModel)]` (and I prefer what you did), your `onChange()` event handler needs to update `this.name` when the event fires:  `onChange($event)` then `onChange(newValue) { this.name = newValue; this.nameChange.emit(this.name);}`

Answer (score 1):

Yes we can use banana property to share the data between child to parent
`[(propertyname)]` and `propertynameChange` emitter event.
Sample plunker available `https://plnkr.co/edit/FYXv36?p=preview`

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Input & @Output to achive 2 way binding between parent and child as mentioned in previous answers.

Otherwise, there another solution, you can use a service that contains your variable, and you can access it with ngModel in the same time from different components (even if they are not parent-child)

Answer (score 0):

you can use a reactive form control and send a parent form to a child.

**parent component:**

.ts

```
myForm: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    control_child: ['']
})
```

.html

```
<child [parentForm]="myForm"></child>
```

**child componenet:**

.ts

```
@Input() parentForm:FormGroup
```

.html

```
<form [formGroup]="parentForm"> 
     <input formControlName="control_child"/>
</form>
```

a parent component form is updated immediately

[here the full code](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://joshblf.medium.com/using-child-components-in-angular-forms-d44e60036664&sa=D&source=hangouts&ust=1654866520505000&usg=AOvVaw2IRnMoY-Jnx4d7YudwNuVe)