# How to make reactive variables between components?

Tags: angular

Lately I've been practicing with component inputs and outputs and this has led me to this example:

In component A, I have

```
@Output () outputVariableA = [hi, hi2, hi3]
```

In component B, I have

```
@Input () inputVariableB [];
```

In component B, I define a function that modifies `inputVariableB`.

How do I make it reactive, between the two variables the modification of `inputVariableB` is reflected in `outputVariableA`.

app.html:

```html
<div class="col s12 event-divider">
    <div class="row">
      <app-upload-refresh
                [InputVariableB] = "OutputVariableA">              
      </app-upload-refresh>
    </div>
```

app.component:

```ts
  @Output() OutputVariableA[]=[];

  constructor(

  ) { }
      if(localStorage.getItem('')){
        for( let localStorageUpdate of JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('reefersToUpdate') )) {
            this.reefersToUpdate.push(localStorageUpdate);
        }
      }
```

componentb.component

```ts
@Input() InputVariableB:Observable<any>[];
onHacerSubida(){
  InputVariableB = []
}
```

Comment: Man that is like the basics you have 1000s of videos on YouTube on intercomponent communication it's also explained in the tutorial section on angular docs.

Comment: I asking this issue because i don't find it

Comment: providing codes / plunker would help..

Comment: Literally type in angular component communication.. in YouTube search https://youtu.be/fPtacabLEJc you can't expect community to do the homework for you.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: Don't [cross-post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/94731). What's the problem with [the code you already got written for you](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/94600)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe this is an other example that I can't get

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 : two way binding inside parent/child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35623868/angular2-two-way-binding-inside-parent-child-component)

Answer (score 1):

if the **component A** and **Component B** are **parent and child** you can do the two way communication using the **@input** binding and **@Output** emitters ([refer this code](https://plnkr.co/edit/ubtMXpGefgybGK4A3Pho?p=preview) )

in component-A

```
  @Input()
   valuetoAfromB:string;
   @Output()
   valueChangeEventAtoB:EventEmitter;
```

and if the **Component A** and **Component B** are **sibling components**, the communication can be done using **shared service** [(refer this code)](https://embed.plnkr.co/P8xCEwSKgcOg07pwDrlO/)

Answer (score 0):

In order to pass the output back, you must actually emit it, so you have your EventEmitter, and your input in the child component.

```
@Input() data: Object;
@Output() updatedData: EventEmitter<Object> = new EventEmitter<Object>();
```

Then, you have a function that emits your updated variable from the child component after changes have been made.

```
passData() {this.updatedData.emit(this.updatedDataObject);}
```

In the parent component, you call one of it's functions on the data sent out where the child comonent is declared.

```
<child-component [data]="object" (updatedData)=updateObject($event)></child-component>
```

You can also use @ViewChild to access child methods from the parent component, but for my purposes, I had to use the former.