# Angular2: How to reset input property after it is changed from child component programatically but not changed in parent binding?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, components

I have two components, `parent.component.ts` and `child.component.ts`, the template, `parent.component.html` likes below:

```
<div>
    <child-component [status]="'good'" (click)="changeToBad()"></child-component>
</div>
```

I bind a constant string `good` intentionally to demonstrate my concern. So, initially, the `good` string is passed to the `child component`. But if I change its value in `child.component.ts`, like `this.status = 'bad';`, what will happen?

1. I think the input binding of parent is not `synced` with the child, since from now on they have different status. If I query `console.log(this.status)`, it will say `bad`. If I want to keep them in sync, I have to use some output bindings.
2. How I can do to make sure the input binding still work after the programmatically change. Say, it changes to `bad` for one `tick`, but it changes back to `good` (automatically) since the binding from parent.

Comment: Maybe it is that waht you looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35623868/angular2-two-way-binding-inside-parent-child-component

Comment: @J.S. no it seems different question. What I am looking for is how angular works, theoretically, I definitely know the two way binding. But for this case, no possible to call the output since I used a constant string.

Comment: @Vincent-cm if i'm understand your question properly then you need to send value parent to child and  want to some value from the child to parent.?

Comment: When you pass a constant string to your child and store it in an attribute like `status`  and then change the status from 'good' to 'bad' then your only option is to get access to the status property from parent via `@ViewChild` for example. Passing down constant params via `@Input` will only take affect during the initialization of the child component. For your use case you definately have to use a reference instead of a constant

Answer (score 0):

The parent basically doesn't listen to the change in the child component, unless the child component use the parent as an input, like

```
<child-component [parent]="parent"></child-component>
```

and in the parent component

```
this.parent = this
```

Otherwise, you can create an Output for the status in the children component and the parent component can listen to it

```
@Output() public statusEvt = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
```

and

```
<child-component (statusEvt)="updateStatus($event)"></child-component>
```

so in the parent component, you can add this function

```
public updateStatus(evt: boolean) {
    this.status = evt;
}
```

when you want to emit the change, in the child component, just call

`this.statusEvt.emit(this.status)`